# Continue formatting from old paragraph in new paragraph

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

In the CkEditor5 Classic Editor, if you type a paragraph, format that paragraph (for example, setting font-size and font-family), then start a new paragraph, the new paragraph won't have the formatting of the preceding paragraph applied to it.

How can I change this?

Comment: Do you mean how the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key behaves?

Comment: @Reinmar Yes, when you use the Enter key to start a new paragraph, the font settings aren't copied across.

Comment: That's the default behaviour of the editor now. If you'd like it to be changed, please upvote this ticket: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-enter/issues/40